# jQueryUI with master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, master-pages

So I have recently started using jQuery, jQueryUi and ASP.NET MVC. And I have been trying to use jQueryUi widgets like tabs, menu etc. in MVC pages.

Now, these widgets work perfectly fine when used without a master page. But when there is a master page involved in the picture, it seems to give the error

> object doesn't support property or method 'menu'

or

> object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'

etc.

Now, I have googled this problem and it seems that this is a common problem when using jQuery with master page.

So if anyone can tell me what is the proper way to make these things work with master pages please let me know.

And I have not posted a code because this always happens!! I have tried different code, different pages and I have always copied the code straight from jQueryUi website. So the code must be right. And it does work perfectly well without master pages! So I am looking for a general solution.. not just solution for a particular code.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Its not a usual problem with jQuery and Master Page. The problem is about our understanding of Master Pages and referring files. Please add the code you tried!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. apparently the order in which the  tags are written matters...

for me.. this is worked..

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: jQuery UI uses functions of jQuery, so jQuery must be loaded first. Keep this is mind with all jQuery plugins. Always put jQuery on top.